# можно ли перенаправить на главную ,если пользователь набирает в url путь к файлу(папке)?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Такой вопрос: например, какой-нибудь умник хочет ввести именно путь к файлу (например, не `sie/category` ,а `site/views/category/index.php`), могу ли я распознать это и перенаправить его на главную страницу (`site/`)?

Answer (score 1):

в корневом .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule '^site/views/(.*)(.php)$' /site [R=302,L]
```

Comment: при таком варианте server error, я хочу redirect ,если это возможно

Comment: @TofiqŞamedov исправил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Сразу возникает вопрос: зачем? Что пытаетесь скрыть? Это как-то связано с SEO (хотите избежать дубликатов...)?

Всё можно сделать.

1. Посредством самого движка (самописного и/или фреймворка).
2. Посредством веб-сервера. В вашем случае как я понимаю Apache: через .htaccess

Что лучше в вашем случае я не знаю, потому что не знаю:

1. Что у вас за движок и как в нем настраиваются маршрутов.
2. Как выглядят эти маршруты.

**Если через .htaccess смотрите в сторону:**

- [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)
- [Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
- [301 редирект (переадресация) через .htaccess](https://web-optimizator.com/301-redirekt-htaccess/) (первое, что попалось)

Нужно будет прописывать для каждой группы маршрута.

**Если через движок сайта** (PHP-скрипты) — нужно знать как у вас эти маршруты организованы и через что настраиваются.

Вам, как я понимаю важно, чтобы была переадресация вводимой пользователем страницы (URL) на соответствующую страницу (URL)? И только, если такой страницы не существует — веб-сервер должен вернуть 404 код.